# remove everything after second occurrence even if dash occur in domain

Tags: javascript, regex

i got links for example:

```
abc.pri-from-somestring
abc-de.pri-idx-somestring
abc.org.au-sop-somestring
```

the result mi looking for from the example links is"

```
abc.pri
abc-de.pri
abc.org.au
```

what im trying to get is the domain out of those string combinations.
the main problem is that links can have dashes in them or 2 dots so im stuck.

i did many splits and join but there is many combinations.
i think the best way is with regex and i don't have enough experience with.
any other solution will be fine.
this works but only if there is a dash after the domain
^([^-\d]+)

any help will be very appreciated
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
^.*[.][^-]*
```

Basically just get everything up until and including the last dot, and then get every up until but excluding the last dash (if one exists).